# how to stop default navigation bar pop swiping in react-native

Tags: react-native, navigationbar

i am getting struggling with this issue that how to stop the navigation bar pop swiping, if possible can any one give me suggestions that how to resolve it [image]

as shown in the above image, when i was in the Property page,when i swipe from that page it goes to the previous page, this is at the time of swipe, it shows that when i swipe from Property it goes to results screen.I wanted to stop it, any help much appreciated

Answer (score 13):

You can prevent all gestures by adding this to your Navigator

```
configureScene={(route) => ({
      ...Navigator.SceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJump,
      gestures: false
    })}
```

you can also disable this per route by adding this when you push the route

```
sceneConfig: {
    ...Navigator.SceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJump,
    gestures: {} //or null
  }
```